# Overloading global operator new/delete in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload the global operator new and delete for a performance sensitive application. I have read the concerns described at http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30642&seqNum=3 and the recommendations to use Intel TBB's allocator http://www.intel.com/technology/itj/2007/v11i4/5-foundations/5-memory.htm

Since I am overloading new and delete for the first time, I have a few questions.

Should I include my new header Allocator.h (or Pre.h) containing the overloaded new function in all files containing "new" calls? This is tedious.

Or should I use "gcc -include Allocator.h ..." which includes Allocator.h (before) into each translation unit? I want to keep the code platform independent as much as possible. Do all compilers support something analogous to "gcc -include"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to overload the global `operator new` and `operator delete`, you just need to implement it. You don't need to explicitly define it everywhere since it already is defined as part of the language.

Edit: If you want to define an operator new that takes different parameters, then you'll need to #include it everywhere. However you do that is up to you; it's mostly a matter of style.

And don't forget to implement all the variants of global operator new and delete: `new`, `new[]`, `delete`, `delete[]`, and the `std::nothrow` variants.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Visual Studio and using precompiled headers, then you can throw the include into there.  I think gcc has some form of precompiling headers as well, which would improve your compilation times as well.