# Changing a C++ application's memory allocation/deallocation method?

Tags: c++, memory-management, allocation

I'm not that advanced in C++ so I hope it's an adequate question.

My situation is that I have a large legacy C code-base system and a small C++ application which I want to integrate it with.

One of the requirements is that this legacy system has its own memory allocation/deallocation methods and they must be used. In other words, since using C++ with, for example, std libraries typically calls `delete()` for memory deallocation, I am interested in replacing that with my legacy system's deallocation functionality which we can call `tfree()` (and allocation done through `talloc()`).

I believe that there must be some way I can inject my own deallocation method in place of `delete()` for the entirety of the C++ application, but I don't know how or if it is at all possible. I would appreciate any help

Comment: Yes it is possible, the standard library uses [`allocators`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) to allocate and deallocate memory. You can write your own and provide it as a template parameter to types like `std::vector`, `std::string` and so on.

Comment: You can also provide your own `operator new` and `operator delete` globally: http://www.flipcode.com/archives/How_To_Find_Memory_Leaks.shtml https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639676/overloading-global-operator-new-delete-in-c I cannot find any modern C++11/14/17 resources on this topic though.

Comment: Famous Meyers 'Effective C++' has a chapter 8 'Customizing new and delete', where this topic widely covered. It may be helpful.

Comment: Interesting, `operator new` and `operator delete` have [special behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new#Global_replacements) when it comes to visibility of the definition.

Comment: @Timo I always believed they are implemented (can be considered) as [weak symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol) for the linker